# JSF: How to redirect a user to a another page according to the value of a specific FacesContext session attribute

Tags: java, session, jsf, redirect, servlet-listeners

In my JSF application, I need to redirect the user from Page A to page B if a session attribute such as userRole has a value of "contributor", and to a page C, for example, if it is "author".

I'm told that I have to implement a page listener, or a session listener perhaps. Although I understand writing a listener class is quite straightforward and standard, I don't know how to set it up on the JSF page itself (to listen to the session).

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session listener ([`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)) is unsuitable since it doesn't have a reference to the current HTTP request/response, which are mandatory in order to change the request/response destination.

Use a filter. To learn more about filters, check our [servlet-filters](/questions/tagged/servlet-filters)  [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). Note that session scoped JSF managed beans are by itself stored as `HttpSession` attribute with the managed bean name as key. You could access them in `doFilter()` method as follows:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("bean");
```

Or when it's to be determined based on a POST action, just return a different outcome in the managed bean action method. Then just make use of (implicit) JSF navigation. Pseudo:

```
public String submit() {
    if (user is contributor) return "pageB";
    if (user is author) return "pageC";
    return "pageA";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice and for always being there for us. Is your advice valid also for "listening" to session-timeouts?

Comment: You're welcome. There you use `HttpSessionListener` or `HttpSessionBindingListener` for, depending on the sole requirement.