# How to redirect to error page in JSF when FacesContext session attribute is not found

Tags: java, session, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am developing a mobile webapp using JSF and Apache myFaces 1.2.9.

During authentication i am calling a servlet which will do the authentication and then set some attribute in the session.

And in every managed bean constructor i am checking for this session attribute and accordingly i am setting a boolean value.That boolean value i am setting as a value for rendered attribute of tr:document.Something like this

```
<tr:document title="someid" rendered="#{controller.render}">
//SOME PAGE CONTENTS
</tr:document>
```

Based on the session attribute,the page may render or not.I want to handle this issue more gracefully.

I came through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958154/jsf-how-to-redirect-a-user-to-a-another-page-according-to-the-value-of-a-specifi) in SO which tells the usage of filters.I used the filter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

I changed the webFilter urlPattern to `/faces/jsp/*` as i want to check the session attribute for each jsp.

In doFilter() method i am checking for session attribute like this
and if it is `null` i am redirecting to invalid user page.

```
System.out.println("In doFilter");
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if (session.getAttribute("myattribute") == null) {
       response.sendRedirect(properties.getProperty(INVALID_USER_REDIRECTURL, true));  // No attribute found, so redirect to Invalid user page.
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res); // attribute found, so just continue request.
            }
```

But i don't see my filter getting fired as i don't see any debug statements which i kept in my filter `init(),doFilter()` methods.

Any help?

EDIT:I just came through this filter mapping in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I suppose myfaces has some filter.Can i have another one of mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the filter to URL pattern where your FacesServlet is mapped.

Comment: -Thanks for the response.I edited my question.Please have a look.

Comment: I meant configure your CUSTOM FILTER in which you added this code such that it intercepts each request that is handled through Faces Servlet. Just copy the URL pattern of your FacesServlet and use it in your custom Filter url mapping

Comment: -My URL pattern of FacesServlet is `/faces/*` .I tried with that only.But no luck.Still i don't see any of my debug statements getting called.

Comment: -I removed webFilter declaration from annotation and kept it in web.xml.I mapped it to `/faces/*`.It started working now.

Comment: cool and interesting. can you post your annotation configuration here. probably you'd imported wrong annotations

Comment: -This is my import statement                                   `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;`

Comment: It seems your container doesn't recognize the anotations  and register it as Filter. may be servlet spec are not proper